# Hot to get value of relationship dynamic Soql

Tags: apex, list, dynamic-soql, nested

I am using the following string in a dynamic soql:

```
   SELECT id, name, orderdate__c, status__c, sold_To_Customer__r.id, sold_To_Customer__r.name, sold_To_Customer__r.customerreference__c, bill_To_Customer__r.id, bill_To_Customer__r.name, bill_To_Customer__r.customerreference__c, Case__r.CaseNumber, Case__r.Reason, Case__r.ContactEmail, Case__r.Description, Campaign__r.Name, Campaign__r.Description FROM Staging_order__c WHERE name = 'SO-1900000020'


 List<sObject> sobjList = Database.query(upper string);
```

I want to get for example the case description. I tried:

```
system.debug(sobjList.get(0).case__r.Description);
```

On saving my class I get the error:

```
Variable does not exist: case__r
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sobjList` is a generic `List<sObject>`. The `sObject` class has no property `Case__r`, and Apex does not resolve properties like this at runtime.

The easiest way to handle this is to declare the result as a `List< Staging_order__c>`, so that the result of `get()` is an actual `Staging_order__c` which has the requisite properties. You could also cast the result of `get()`, but there doesn't seem to be a reason to store this data in a generic sObject list.